# Aligning an Authorize.Net element to the center

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have this Authorize.net element on my page, which is basically authorizing my site for payment, which basically authenticates my site as an authorize.net merchant, but I can't find out how to center it, as I think it looks better this way in my right column, rather than aligned to the left.

Here is the page:
http://www.marioplanet.com

It is on the right column like I said.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`margin:0 auto` on the div with the explicit width set should center it.

Comment: It may be needed `align="center"` or `style="text-align:center;"` for the wrapping element for this trick to work with some IE versions (I can't recall if it happened at IE7 or just IE6)

Comment: Hey, thanks for that tip, I'll double check as that is of course such a huge percentage of users..